# Get taxonomy singular name instead of taxonomy slug inside $taxonomy query

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, taxonomy-meta

I'm trying to echo the taxonomy name inside a for each loop, instead of the category slug at this line :

```
<div class="title"><?php echo $taxonomy; ?></div>
```

I tried :

```
<div class="title"><?php echo $taxonomy->name; ?></div>
```

but I get an error : " Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Here is my code :

```
<?php
$custom_post_type = get_queried_object();
$custom_post_type_name = $custom_post_type->name;
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($custom_post_type_name);
?>

<?php foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) : ?>

    <?php $categories = get_terms(array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => 1,

    )); ?>

    <div id="filters-<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" class="filter-group">

        <div class="title"><?php echo $taxonomy; ?></div>

        <ul class="filters-select" data-filter-group>

            <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
                
                <li>
                    <label><?php echo $category->name; ?></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value=".<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" />
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>

    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

[`get_object_taxonomies()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_object_taxonomies/) by default returns a list of taxonomy names like `category` and `post_tag`. If you want the function to return taxonomy objects instead, then set the second parameter to `objects`:

```php
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($custom_post_type_name, 'objects');
```

And then change your `foreach ()` code to `foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy => $tax_object)`, then use `$tax_object->labels->singular_name` to access the singular label of the specific taxonomy.

Comment: awesome @Sally CJ, works like a charm thanks

Comment: Glad it helped, and you can mark my answer as "correct" if it answered the question. 